# Javascript List With calculator Doesn't Work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried to make a destination calculator with "cakesizeprice" script but whatever i did i can't make it work! I'm a newbie at javascript. Could someone help me where i'm doing wrong?

*Please see the fiddle, the code that i paste here is didn't fit.

[Here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ajolnir/08s8t14t/)

```html
<form id="slider-form" class="main-form" action="http://istanbulprivateservice.com/bookit.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="POST">
  <div class="main_form_navigation">
    <div id="book_car" class="title-form current">BOOKING ONLINE</div>
  </div>
  <div id="book_car_content" class="content-form ">

    <div class="form-block car-type">
      <div class="car-type-select">
        <h4>Pick Up Location</h4>
        <select class="select" id="nereden_y" name="nereden_y" onchange="calculateTotal()">
          <option value="">Select</option>
          <option value="Atatürk Airport (IST)" selected="selected">Atatürk Airport (IST)</option>
          <option value="Sabiha Gökçen Airport (SAW)">Sabiha Gökçen Airport (SAW)</option>
          <option value="Ports - Karaköy, Salıpazarı, Kabataş">Ports - Karaköy, Salıpazarı, Kabataş</option>
          <option value="Old City - Sultanahmet - Sirkeci">Old City - Sultanahmet - Sirkeci</option>
          <option value="Taksim - Beyoğlu, Pera, Nişantaşı">Taksim - Beyoğlu, Pera, Nişantaşı</option>
          <option value="Beşiktaş - Ortaköy">Beşiktaş - Ortaköy</option>
          <option value="Yenikapı - Aksaray, Laleli">Yenikapı - Aksaray, Laleli</option>
          <option value="Bakırköy - Yenibosna, Zeytinburnu, Sefaköy">Bakırköy - Yenibosna, Zeytinburnu, Sefaköy</option>
          <option value="Otogar - Bayrampaşa, Bağcılar, Esenler">Otogar - Bayrampaşa, Bağcılar, Esenler</option>
          <option value="Şişli - Maslak, Levent, Etiler">Şişli - Maslak, Levent, Etiler</option>
          <option value="Topkapı - Fındıkzade, Vatan Cad">Topkapı - Fındıkzade, Vatan Cad</option>
          <option value="Eyüp - Gaziosmanpaşa, Haliç">Eyüp - Gaziosmanpaşa, Haliç</option>
          <option value="Mecidiyeköy - Bomonti, Çağlayan">Mecidiyeköy - Bomonti, Çağlayan</option>
          <option value="Kadıköy - Ataşehir, Bostancı">Kadıköy - Ataşehir, Bostancı</option>
          <option value="Üsküdar - Harem, Haydarpaşa">Üsküdar - Harem, Haydarpaşa</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="form-block car-type">
        <div class="car-type-select">
          <h4>Drop Off Location</h4>
          <select class="select" id="nereye_y" name="nereye_y" onchange="calculateTotal()" sb="88701315">
            <option value="" selected="selected">Select</option>
            <option value="Atatürk Airport (IST)" selected="selected">Atatürk Airport (IST)</option>
            <option value="Sabiha Gökçen Airport (SAW)" selected="selected">Sabiha Gökçen Airport (SAW)</option>
            <option value="Ports - Karaköy, Salıpazarı, Kabataş">Ports - Karaköy, Salıpazarı, Kabataş</option>
            <option value="Old City - Sultanahmet - Sirkeci">Old City - Sultanahmet - Sirkeci</option>
            <option value="Taksim - Beyoğlu, Pera, Nişantaşı">Taksim - Beyoğlu, Pera, Nişantaşı</option>
            <option value="Beşiktaş - Ortaköy">Beşiktaş - Ortaköy</option>
            <option value="Yenikapı - Aksaray, Laleli">Yenikapı - Aksaray, Laleli</option>
            <option value="Bakırköy - Yenibosna, Zeytinburnu, Sefaköy" selected="selected">Bakırköy - Yenibosna, Zeytinburnu, Sefaköy</option>
            <option value="Otogar - Bayrampaşa, Bağcılar, Esenler">Otogar - Bayrampaşa, Bağcılar, Esenler</option>
            <option value="Şişli - Maslak, Levent, Etiler">Şişli - Maslak, Levent, Etiler</option>
            <option value="Topkapı - Fındıkzade, Vatan Cad" selected="selected">Topkapı - Fındıkzade, Vatan Cad</option>
            <option value="Eyüp - Gaziosmanpaşa, Haliç">Eyüp - Gaziosmanpaşa, Haliç</option>
            <option value="Mecidiyeköy - Bomonti, Çağlayan">Mecidiyeköy - Bomonti, Çağlayan</option>
            <option value="Avcılar - Beylikdüzü, Esenyurt">Avcılar - Beylikdüzü, Esenyurt</option>
            <option value="Pendik - Tuzla, Kurtköy">Pendik - Tuzla, Kurtköy</option>
            <option value="Kadıköy - Ataşehir, Bostancı">Kadıköy - Ataşehir, Bostancı</option>
            <option value="Silivri - Selimpaşa, Kumburgaz">Silivri - Selimpaşa, Kumburgaz</option>
            <option value="Üsküdar - Harem, Haydarpaşa" selected="selected">Üsküdar - Harem, Haydarpaşa</option>
            <option value="Kartal - Maltepe, Ümraniye">Kartal - Maltepe, Ümraniye</option>
            <option value="Kilyos">Kilyos</option>
            <option value="Şile - Ağva">Şile - Ağva</option>
            <option value="Beykoz - Kavacık, And.Hisarı">Beykoz - Kavacık, And.Hisarı</option>
            <option value="Sarıyer- Tarabya, Yeniköy">Sarıyer- Tarabya, Yeniköy</option>
            <option value="Gebze">Gebze</option>
            <option value="Izmit">Izmit</option>
            <option value="Bursa - Uludağ">Bursa - Uludağ</option>
            <option value="Bolu - Abant">Bolu - Abant</option>
            <option value="Yalova">Yalova</option>
            <option value="Çanakkale - Gelibolu">Çanakkale - Gelibolu</option>
            <option value="Edirne - Tekirdağ">Edirne - Tekirdağ</option>
          </select>
        </div>


        <h4>Passenger</h4>
        <div class="car-type-select">
          <select class="select" id="kisi_y" name="kisi_y" onchange="calculateTotal()">
            <option selected="selected" value="Standart 4 Pax">Standart 4 Pax</option>
            <option value="Minibus 8 pax" selected="selected">Minibus 8 pax</option>
            <option value="Midibus 13 pax" selected="selected">Midibus 13 pax</option>
          </select>

          <h4>Price</h4>
          <textarea class="price-text" id="totalPrice" name="totalPrice" readonly="" style="display: block;">65€</textarea>
```

Comment: Is this the *shortest* code necessary to reproduce the problem? What exactly does "I can't make it work" mean? Figuring out the shortest code necessary to reproduce the bug not only makes it easier for us to help, but may also lead to you actually finding the cause in the process.

Comment: `*Please see the fiddle, the code that i paste here is didn't fit.` So you are attaching a non related code and a link with the correct code. Is not easiest put here the correct code? Some people make hard the simplest things.

Comment: The code that i wrote here not necessary, complete code is in the fiddle, i wrote a script to that form to calculate destinations according to values but the script doesn't calculate.

Comment: The complete code is not fit in here because i exceed the character limit.

Comment: In your code add just 1 or 2 `<option>` in `<select>`, Paste your java script in the **JavaScript section** of the fiddle(bottom left box)

Comment: There is already a script in the js section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In your fiddle, the JS code was set to be loaded onLoad. This would mean it's wrapped with document.onLoad and won't be available globally, so your HTML tags wouldn't be able to access your functions.
2. No element with id/class "includeInscription" was defined in your html.

I removed the function `inscriptionPrice()` as well as the reference to it in the function `calculatePrice()`. Check below.

```js
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["slider-form"]["date_from"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("Date and Time must be filled out");
  return false;
  }
var y=document.forms["slider-form"]["nereden_y"].value;
if (y==null || y=="")
  {
  alert("Pick-up Location must be selected");
  return false;
  }
var y=document.forms["slider-form"]["nereye_y"].value;
if (y==null || y=="")
  {
  alert("Drop-off Location must be selected");
  return false;
  }
}
 
 
 var nereden_bedel = new Array();
 nereden_bedel["Atatürk Airport (IST)"]=0;
 nereden_bedel["Sabiha Gökçen Airport (SAW)"]=0;
 nereden_bedel["Ports - Karaköy, Salıpazarı, Kabataş"]=0;
 nereden_bedel["Old City - Sultanahmet - Sirkeci"]=0;
 nereden_bedel["Taksim - Beyoğlu, Pera, Nişantaşı"]=0;
 nereden_bedel["Beşiktaş - Ortaköy"]=0;
 nereden_bedel["Yenikapı - Aksaray, Laleli"]=0;
 nereden_bedel["Bakırköy - Yenibosna, Zeytinburnu, Sefaköy"]=0;
 nereden_bedel["Otogar - Bayrampaşa, Bağcılar, Esenler"]=0;
 nereden_bedel["Şişli - Maslak, Levent, Etiler"]=0;
 nereden_bedel["Topkapı - Fındıkzade, Vatan Cad"]=0;
 nereden_bedel["Eyüp - Gaziosmanpaşa, Haliç"]=0;
 nereden_bedel["Mecidiyeköy - Bomonti, Çağlayan"]=0;
 nereden_bedel["Kadıköy - Ataşehir, Bostancı"]=0;
 nereden_bedel["Üsküdar - Harem, Haydarpaşa"]=0;

 var Ap_bedel= new Array();
 Ap_bedel["Atatürk Airport (IST)"]=0;
 Ap_bedel["Sabiha Gökçen Airport (SAW)"]=60; 
 Ap_bedel["Ports - Karaköy, Salıpazarı, Kabataş"]=35;
 Ap_bedel["Old City - Sultanahmet - Sirkeci"]=25;
 Ap_bedel["Taksim - Beyoğlu, Pera, Nişantaşı"]=30;
 Ap_bedel["Beşiktaş - Ortaköy"]=40;
 Ap_bedel["Yenikapı - Aksaray, Laleli"]=25;
 Ap_bedel["Bakırköy - Yenibosna, Zeytinburnu, Sefaköy"]=25;
 Ap_bedel["Otogar - Bayrampaşa, Bağcılar, Esenler"]=30;
 Ap_bedel["Şişli - Maslak, Levent, Etiler"]=40;
 Ap_bedel["Topkapı - Fındıkzade, Vatan Cad"]=25;
 Ap_bedel["Eyüp - Gaziosmanpaşa, Haliç"]=35;
 Ap_bedel["Mecidiyeköy - Bomonti, Çağlayan"]=40;
 Ap_bedel["Avcılar - Beylikdüzü, Esenyurt"]=35;
 Ap_bedel["Pendik - Tuzla, Kurtköy"]=70;
 Ap_bedel["Kadıköy - Ataşehir, Bostancı"]=55;
 Ap_bedel["Silivri - Selimpaşa, Kumburgaz"]=100;
 Ap_bedel["Üsküdar - Harem, Haydarpaşa"]=50;
 Ap_bedel["Kartal - Maltepe, Ümraniye"]=60;
 Ap_bedel["Kilyos"]=80;
 Ap_bedel["Şile - Ağva"]=85;
 Ap_bedel["Beykoz - Kavacık, And.Hisarı"]=55;
 Ap_bedel["Sarıyer- Tarabya, Yeniköy"]=45;
 Ap_bedel["Gebze"]=75;
 Ap_bedel["Izmit"]=120;
 Ap_bedel["Bursa - Uludağ"]=320;
 Ap_bedel["Bolu - Abant"]=320;
 Ap_bedel["Yalova"]=220;
 Ap_bedel["Çanakkale - Gelibolu"]=350;
 Ap_bedel["Edirne - Tekirdağ"]=350;
 
 var Bp_bedel= new Array();
 Bp_bedel["Atatürk Airport (IST)"]=60;
 Bp_bedel["Sabiha Gökçen Airport (SAW)"]=0;
 Bp_bedel["Ports - Karaköy, Salıpazarı, Kabataş"]=55;
 Bp_bedel["Old City - Sultanahmet - Sirkeci"]=55;
 Bp_bedel["Taksim - Beyoğlu, Pera, Nişantaşı"]=55;
 Bp_bedel["Beşiktaş - Ortaköy"]=55;
 Bp_bedel["Yenikapı - Aksaray, Laleli"]=55;
 Bp_bedel["Bakırköy - Yenibosna, Zeytinburnu, Sefaköy"]=60;
 Bp_bedel["Otogar - Bayrampaşa, Bağcılar, Esenler"]=60;
 Bp_bedel["Şişli - Maslak, Levent, Etiler"]=55;
 Bp_bedel["Topkapı - Fındıkzade, Vatan Cad"]=55;
 Bp_bedel["Eyüp - Gaziosmanpaşa, Haliç"]=60;
 Bp_bedel["Mecidiyeköy - Bomonti, Çağlayan"]=60;
 Bp_bedel["Avcılar - Beylikdüzü, Esenyurt"]=80;
 Bp_bedel["Pendik - Tuzla, Kurtköy"]=65;
 Bp_bedel["Kadıköy - Ataşehir, Bostancı"]=55;
 Bp_bedel["Silivri - Selimpaşa, Kumburgaz"]=120;
 Bp_bedel["Üsküdar - Harem, Haydarpaşa"]=50;
 Bp_bedel["Kartal - Maltepe, Ümraniye"]=55;
 Bp_bedel["Kilyos"]=95;
 Bp_bedel["Şile - Ağva"]=85;
 Bp_bedel["Beykoz - Kavacık, And.Hisarı"]=55;
 Bp_bedel["Sarıyer- Tarabya, Yeniköy"]=65;
 Bp_bedel["Gebze"]=60;
 Bp_bedel["Izmit"]=95;
 Bp_bedel["Bursa - Uludağ"]=320;
 Bp_bedel["Bolu - Abant"]=320;
 Bp_bedel["Yalova"]=220;
 Bp_bedel["Çanakkale - Gelibolu"]=350;
 Bp_bedel["Edirne - Tekirdağ"]=350;
 
 var Cp_bedel= new Array();
 Cp_bedel["Atatürk Airport (IST)"]=35;
 Cp_bedel["Sabiha Gökçen Airport (SAW)"]=55;
 Cp_bedel["Ports - Karaköy, Salıpazarı, Kabataş"]=0;
 Cp_bedel["Old City - Sultanahmet - Sirkeci"]=25;
 Cp_bedel["Taksim - Beyoğlu, Pera, Nişantaşı"]=30;
 Cp_bedel["Beşiktaş - Ortaköy"]=30;
 Cp_bedel["Yenikapı - Aksaray, Laleli"]=25;
 Cp_bedel["Bakırköy - Yenibosna, Zeytinburnu, Sefaköy"]=30;
 Cp_bedel["Otogar - Bayrampaşa, Bağcılar, Esenler"]=30;
 Cp_bedel["Şişli - Maslak, Levent, Etiler"]=40;
 Cp_bedel["Topkapı - Fındıkzade, Vatan Cad"]=30;
 Cp_bedel["Eyüp - Gaziosmanpaşa, Haliç"]=45;
 Cp_bedel["Mecidiyeköy - Bomonti, Çağlayan"]=40;
 Cp_bedel["Avcılar - Beylikdüzü, Esenyurt"]=45;
 Cp_bedel["Pendik - Tuzla, Kurtköy"]=55;
 Cp_bedel["Kadıköy - Ataşehir, Bostancı"]=50;
 Cp_bedel["Silivri - Selimpaşa, Kumburgaz"]=80;
 Cp_bedel["Üsküdar - Harem, Haydarpaşa"]=50;
 Cp_bedel["Kartal - Maltepe, Ümraniye"]=50;
 Cp_bedel["Kilyos"]=80;
 Cp_bedel["Şile - Ağva"]=85;
 Cp_bedel["Beykoz - Kavacık, And.Hisarı"]=55;
 Cp_bedel["Sarıyer- Tarabya, Yeniköy"]=40;
 Cp_bedel["Gebze"]=75;
 Cp_bedel["Izmit"]=110;
 Cp_bedel["Bursa - Uludağ"]=320;
 Cp_bedel["Bolu - Abant"]=320;
 Cp_bedel["Yalova"]=220;
 Cp_bedel["Çanakkale - Gelibolu"]=350;
 Cp_bedel["Edirne - Tekirdağ"]=350;
 
 var Dp_bedel= new Array();
 Dp_bedel["Atatürk Airport (IST)"]=25;
 Dp_bedel["Sabiha Gökçen Airport (SAW)"]=55;
 Dp_bedel["Ports - Karaköy, Salıpazarı, Kabataş"]=25;
 Dp_bedel["Old City - Sultanahmet - Sirkeci"]=0;
 Dp_bedel["Taksim - Beyoğlu, Pera, Nişantaşı"]=30;
 Dp_bedel["Beşiktaş - Ortaköy"]=30;
 Dp_bedel["Yenikapı - Aksaray, Laleli"]=25;
 Dp_bedel["Bakırköy - Yenibosna, Zeytinburnu, Sefaköy"]=25;
 Dp_bedel["Otogar - Bayrampaşa, Bağcılar, Esenler"]=25;
 Dp_bedel["Şişli - Maslak, Levent, Etiler"]=30;
 Dp_bedel["Topkapı - Fındıkzade, Vatan Cad"]=25;
 Dp_bedel["Eyüp - Gaziosmanpaşa, Haliç"]=35;
 Dp_bedel["Mecidiyeköy - Bomonti, Çağlayan"]=35;
 Dp_bedel["Avcılar - Beylikdüzü, Esenyurt"]=45;
 Dp_bedel["Pendik - Tuzla, Kurtköy"]=55;
 Dp_bedel["Kadıköy - Ataşehir, Bostancı"]=50;
 Dp_bedel["Silivri - Selimpaşa, Kumburgaz"]=80;
 Dp_bedel["Üsküdar - Harem, Haydarpaşa"]=50;
 Dp_bedel["Kartal - Maltepe, Ümraniye"]=50;
 Dp_bedel["Kilyos"]=80;
 Dp_bedel["Şile - Ağva"]=85;
 Dp_bedel["Beykoz - Kavacık, And.Hisarı"]=55;
 Dp_bedel["Sarıyer- Tarabya, Yeniköy"]=45;
 Dp_bedel["Gebze"]=75;
 Dp_bedel["Izmit"]=110;
 Dp_bedel["Bursa - Uludağ"]=320;
 Dp_bedel["Bolu - Abant"]=320;
 Dp_bedel["Yalova"]=220;
 Dp_bedel["Çanakkale - Gelibolu"]=350;
 Dp_bedel["Edirne - Tekirdağ"]=350;
 
 var Ep_bedel= new Array();
 Ep_bedel["Atatürk Airport (IST)"]=30;
 Ep_bedel["Sabiha Gökçen Airport (SAW)"]=55;
 Ep_bedel["Ports - Karaköy, Salıpazarı, Kabataş"]=30;
 Ep_bedel["Old City - Sultanahmet - Sirkeci"]=30;
 Ep_bedel["Taksim - Beyoğlu, Pera, Nişantaşı"]=0;
 Ep_bedel["Beşiktaş - Ortaköy"]=30;
 Ep_bedel["Yenikapı - Aksaray, Laleli"]=25;
 Ep_bedel["Bakırköy - Yenibosna, Zeytinburnu, Sefaköy"]=30;
 Ep_bedel["Otogar - Bayrampaşa, Bağcılar, Esenler"]=30;
 Ep_bedel["Şişli - Maslak, Levent, Etiler"]=30;
 Ep_bedel["Topkapı - Fındıkzade, Vatan Cad"]=25;
 Ep_bedel["Eyüp - Gaziosmanpaşa, Haliç"]=45;
 Ep_bedel["Mecidiyeköy - Bomonti, Çağlayan"]=35;
 Ep_bedel["Avcılar - Beylikdüzü, Esenyurt"]=45;
 Ep_bedel["Pendik - Tuzla, Kurtköy"]=55;
 Ep_bedel["Kadıköy - Ataşehir, Bostancı"]=50;
 Ep_bedel["Silivri - Selimpaşa, Kumburgaz"]=80;
 Ep_bedel["Üsküdar - Harem, Haydarpaşa"]=50;
 Ep_bedel["Kartal - Maltepe, Ümraniye"]=50;
 Ep_bedel["Kilyos"]=80;
 Ep_bedel["Şile - Ağva"]=85;
 Ep_bedel["Beykoz - Kavacık, And.Hisarı"]=55;
 Ep_bedel["Sarıyer- Tarabya, Yeniköy"]=40;
 Ep_bedel["Gebze"]=75;
 Ep_bedel["Izmit"]=110;
 Ep_bedel["Bursa - Uludağ"]=320;
 Ep_bedel["Bolu - Abant"]=320;
 Ep_bedel["Yalova"]=220;
 Ep_bedel["Çanakkale - Gelibolu"]=350;
 Ep_bedel["Edirne - Tekirdağ"]=350;
 
 var Fp_bedel= new Array();
 Fp_bedel["Atatürk Airport (IST)"]=40;
 Fp_bedel["Sabiha Gökçen Airport (SAW)"]=55;
 Fp_bedel["Ports - Karaköy, Salıpazarı, Kabataş"]=30;
 Fp_bedel["Old City - Sultanahmet - Sirkeci"]=30;
 Fp_bedel["Taksim - Beyoğlu, Pera, Nişantaşı"]=30;
 Fp_bedel["Beşiktaş - Ortaköy"]=0;
 Fp_bedel["Yenikapı - Aksaray, Laleli"]=25;
 Fp_bedel["Bakırköy - Yenibosna, Zeytinburnu, Sefaköy"]=40;
 Fp_bedel["Otogar - Bayrampaşa, Bağcılar, Esenler"]=35;
 Fp_bedel["Şişli - Maslak, Levent, Etiler"]=30;
 Fp_bedel["Topkapı - Fındıkzade, Vatan Cad"]=30;
 Fp_bedel["Eyüp - Gaziosmanpaşa, Haliç"]=0;
 Fp_bedel["Mecidiyeköy - Bomonti, Çağlayan"]=15;
 Fp_bedel["Avcılar - Beylikdüzü, Esenyurt"]=45;
 Fp_bedel["Pendik - Tuzla, Kurtköy"]=55;
 Fp_bedel["Kadıköy - Ataşehir, Bostancı"]=50;
 Fp_bedel["Silivri - Selimpaşa, Kumburgaz"]=85;
 Fp_bedel["Üsküdar - Harem, Haydarpaşa"]=50;
 Fp_bedel["Kartal - Maltepe, Ümraniye"]=55;
 Fp_bedel["Kilyos"]=80;
 Fp_bedel["Şile - Ağva"]=85;
 Fp_bedel["Beykoz - Kavacık, And.Hisarı"]=0;
 Fp_bedel["Sarıyer- Tarabya, Yeniköy"]=40;
 Fp_bedel["Gebze"]=75;
 Fp_bedel["Izmit"]=110;
 Fp_bedel["Bursa - Uludağ"]=320;
 Fp_bedel["Bolu - Abant"]=320;
 Fp_bedel["Yalova"]=220;
 Fp_bedel["Çanakkale - Gelibolu"]=350;
 Fp_bedel["Edirne - Tekirdağ"]=350;
 
 var Gp_bedel= new Array();
 Gp_bedel["Atatürk Airport (IST)"]=25;
 Gp_bedel["Sabiha Gökçen Airport (SAW)"]=55;
 Gp_bedel["Ports - Karaköy, Salıpazarı, Kabataş"]=25;
 Gp_bedel["Old City - Sultanahmet - Sirkeci"]=25;
 Gp_bedel["Taksim - Beyoğlu, Pera, Nişantaşı"]=35;
 Gp_bedel["Beşiktaş - Ortaköy"]=0;
 Gp_bedel["Yenikapı - Aksaray, Laleli"]=25;
 Gp_bedel["Bakırköy - Yenibosna, Zeytinburnu, Sefaköy"]=25;
 Gp_bedel["Otogar - Bayrampaşa, Bağcılar, Esenler"]=30;
 Gp_bedel["Şişli - Maslak, Levent, Etiler"]=30;
 Gp_bedel["Topkapı - Fındıkzade, Vatan Cad"]=25;
 Gp_bedel["Eyüp - Gaziosmanpaşa, Haliç"]=0;
 Gp_bedel["Mecidiyeköy - Bomonti, Çağlayan"]=0;
 Gp_bedel["Avcılar - Beylikdüzü, Esenyurt"]=45;
 Gp_bedel["Pendik - Tuzla, Kurtköy"]=60;
 Gp_bedel["Kadıköy - Ataşehir, Bostancı"]=55;
 Gp_bedel["Silivri - Selimpaşa, Kumburgaz"]=80;
 Gp_bedel["Üsküdar - Harem, Haydarpaşa"]=50;
 Gp_bedel["Kartal - Maltepe, Ümraniye"]=50;
 Gp_bedel["Kilyos"]=80;
 Gp_bedel["Şile - Ağva"]=85;
 Gp_bedel["Beykoz - Kavacık, And.Hisarı"]=0;
 Gp_bedel["Sarıyer- Tarabya, Yeniköy"]=45;
 Gp_bedel["Gebze"]=75;
 Gp_bedel["Izmit"]=110;
 Gp_bedel["Bursa - Uludağ"]=320;
 Gp_bedel["Bolu - Abant"]=320;
 Gp_bedel["Yalova"]=220;
 Gp_bedel["Çanakkale - Gelibolu"]=350;
 Gp_bedel["Edirne - Tekirdağ"]=350;
 
 var Hp_bedel= new Array();
 Hp_bedel["Atatürk Airport (IST)"]=25;
 Hp_bedel["Sabiha Gökçen Airport (SAW)"]=60;
 Hp_bedel["Ports - Karaköy, Salıpazarı, Kabataş"]=30;
 Hp_bedel["Old City - Sultanahmet - Sirkeci"]=25;
 Hp_bedel["Taksim - Beyoğlu, Pera, Nişantaşı"]=30;
 Hp_bedel["Beşiktaş - Ortaköy"]=40;
 Hp_bedel["Yenikapı - Aksaray, Laleli"]=25;
 Hp_bedel["Bakırköy - Yenibosna, Zeytinburnu, Sefaköy"]=0;
 Hp_bedel["Otogar - Bayrampaşa, Bağcılar, Esenler"]=30;
 Hp_bedel["Şişli - Maslak, Levent, Etiler"]=40;
 Hp_bedel["Topkapı - Fındıkzade, Vatan Cad"]=25;
 Hp_bedel["Eyüp - Gaziosmanpaşa, Haliç"]=0;
 Hp_bedel["Mecidiyeköy - Bomonti, Çağlayan"]=30;
 Hp_bedel["Avcılar - Beylikdüzü, Esenyurt"]=35;
 Hp_bedel["Pendik - Tuzla, Kurtköy"]=75;
 Hp_bedel["Kadıköy - Ataşehir, Bostancı"]=65;
 Hp_bedel["Silivri - Selimpaşa, Kumburgaz"]=70;
 Hp_bedel["Üsküdar - Harem, Haydarpaşa"]=65;
 Hp_bedel["Kartal - Maltepe, Ümraniye"]=65;
 Hp_bedel["Kilyos"]=80;
 Hp_bedel["Şile - Ağva"]=85;
 Hp_bedel["Beykoz - Kavacık, And.Hisarı"]=0;
 Hp_bedel["Sarıyer- Tarabya, Yeniköy"]=45;
 Hp_bedel["Gebze"]=85;
 Hp_bedel["Izmit"]=120;
 Hp_bedel["Bursa - Uludağ"]=320;
 Hp_bedel["Bolu - Abant"]=320;
 Hp_bedel["Yalova"]=220;
 Hp_bedel["Çanakkale - Gelibolu"]=350;
 Hp_bedel["Edirne - Tekirdağ"]=350;
 
 var Ip_bedel= new Array();
 Ip_bedel["Atatürk Airport (IST)"]=30;
 Ip_bedel["Sabiha Gökçen Airport (SAW)"]=60;
 Ip_bedel["Ports - Karaköy, Salıpazarı, Kabataş"]=30;
 Ip_bedel["Old City - Sultanahmet - Sirkeci"]=25;
 Ip_bedel["Taksim - Beyoğlu, Pera, Nişantaşı"]=30;
 Ip_bedel["Beşiktaş - Ortaköy"]=35;
 Ip_bedel["Yenikapı - Aksaray, Laleli"]=25;
 Ip_bedel["Bakırköy - Yenibosna, Zeytinburnu, Sefaköy"]=30;
 Ip_bedel["Otogar - Bayrampaşa, Bağcılar, Esenler"]=0;
 Ip_bedel["Şişli - Maslak, Levent, Etiler"]=40;
 Ip_bedel["Topkapı - Fındıkzade, Vatan Cad"]=25;
 Ip_bedel["Eyüp - Gaziosmanpaşa, Haliç"]=0;
 Ip_bedel["Mecidiyeköy - Bomonti, Çağlayan"]=25;
 Ip_bedel["Avcılar - Beylikdüzü, Esenyurt"]=45;
 Ip_bedel["Pendik - Tuzla, Kurtköy"]=55;
 Ip_bedel["Kadıköy - Ataşehir, Bostancı"]=60;
 Ip_bedel["Silivri - Selimpaşa, Kumburgaz"]=80;
 Ip_bedel["Üsküdar - Harem, Haydarpaşa"]=60;
 Ip_bedel["Kartal - Maltepe, Ümraniye"]=55;
 Ip_bedel["Kilyos"]=80;
 Ip_bedel["Şile - Ağva"]=85;
 Ip_bedel["Beykoz - Kavacık, And.Hisarı"]=80;
 Ip_bedel["Sarıyer- Tarabya, Yeniköy"]=50;
 Ip_bedel["Gebze"]=80;
 Ip_bedel["Izmit"]=110;
 Ip_bedel["Bursa - Uludağ"]=320;
 Ip_bedel["Bolu - Abant"]=320;
 Ip_bedel["Yalova"]=220;
 Ip_bedel["Çanakkale - Gelibolu"]=350;
 Ip_bedel["Edirne - Tekirdağ"]=350;
 
 var Jp_bedel= new Array();
 Jp_bedel["Atatürk Airport (IST)"]=40;
 Jp_bedel["Sabiha Gökçen Airport (SAW)"]=55;
 Jp_bedel["Ports - Karaköy, Salıpazarı, Kabataş"]=40;
 Jp_bedel["Old City - Sultanahmet - Sirkeci"]=30;
 Jp_bedel["Taksim - Beyoğlu, Pera, Nişantaşı"]=30;
 Jp_bedel["Beşiktaş - Ortaköy"]=30;
 Jp_bedel["Yenikapı - Aksaray, Laleli"]=30;
 Jp_bedel["Bakırköy - Yenibosna, Zeytinburnu, Sefaköy"]=40;
 Jp_bedel["Otogar - Bayrampaşa, Bağcılar, Esenler"]=40;
 Jp_bedel["Şişli - Maslak, Levent, Etiler"]=0;
 Jp_bedel["Topkapı - Fındıkzade, Vatan Cad"]=30;
 Jp_bedel["Eyüp - Gaziosmanpaşa, Haliç"]=30;
 Jp_bedel["Mecidiyeköy - Bomonti, Çağlayan"]=0;
 Jp_bedel["Avcılar - Beylikdüzü, Esenyurt"]=50;
 Jp_bedel["Pendik - Tuzla, Kurtköy"]=80;
 Jp_bedel["Kadıköy - Ataşehir, Bostancı"]=40;
 Jp_bedel["Silivri - Selimpaşa, Kumburgaz"]=80;
 Jp_bedel["Üsküdar - Harem, Haydarpaşa"]=50;
 Jp_bedel["Kartal - Maltepe, Ümraniye"]=110;
 Jp_bedel["Kilyos"]=110;
 Jp_bedel["Şile - Ağva"]=100;
 Jp_bedel["Beykoz - Kavacık, And.Hisarı"]=80;
 Jp_bedel["Sarıyer- Tarabya, Yeniköy"]=50;
 Jp_bedel["Gebze"]=110;
 Jp_bedel["Izmit"]=120;
 Jp_bedel["Bursa - Uludağ"]=320;
 Jp_bedel["Bolu - Abant"]=320;
 Jp_bedel["Yalova"]=220;
 Jp_bedel["Çanakkale - Gelibolu"]=350;
 Jp_bedel["Edirne - Tekirdağ"]=350;
 
 var Kp_bedel= new Array();
 Kp_bedel["Atatürk Airport (IST)"]=25;
 Kp_bedel["Sabiha Gökçen Airport (SAW)"]=55;
 Kp_bedel["Ports - Karaköy, Salıpazarı, Kabataş"]=30;
 Kp_bedel["Old City - Sultanahmet - Sirkeci"]=25;
 Kp_bedel["Taksim - Beyoğlu, Pera, Nişantaşı"]=25;
 Kp_bedel["Beşiktaş - Ortaköy"]=30;
 Kp_bedel["Yenikapı - Aksaray, Laleli"]=25;
 Kp_bedel["Bakırköy - Yenibosna, Zeytinburnu, Sefaköy"]=25;
 Kp_bedel["Otogar - Bayrampaşa, Bağcılar, Esenler"]=25;
 Kp_bedel["Şişli - Maslak, Levent, Etiler"]=30;
 Kp_bedel["Topkapı - Fındıkzade, Vatan Cad"]=0;
 Kp_bedel["Eyüp - Gaziosmanpaşa, Haliç"]=30;
 Kp_bedel["Mecidiyeköy - Bomonti, Çağlayan"]=30;
 Kp_bedel["Avcılar - Beylikdüzü, Esenyurt"]=45;
 Kp_bedel["Pendik - Tuzla, Kurtköy"]=60;
 Kp_bedel["Kadıköy - Ataşehir, Bostancı"]=55;
 Kp_bedel["Silivri - Selimpaşa, Kumburgaz"]=80;
 Kp_bedel["Üsküdar - Harem, Haydarpaşa"]=55;
 Kp_bedel["Kartal - Maltepe, Ümraniye"]=60;
 Kp_bedel["Kilyos"]=80;
 Kp_bedel["Şile - Ağva"]=85;
 Kp_bedel["Beykoz - Kavacık, And.Hisarı"]=80;
 Kp_bedel["Sarıyer- Tarabya, Yeniköy"]=40;
 Kp_bedel["Gebze"]=80;
 Kp_bedel["Izmit"]=115;
 Kp_bedel["Bursa - Uludağ"]=320;
 Kp_bedel["Bolu - Abant"]=320;
 Kp_bedel["Yalova"]=220;
 Kp_bedel["Çanakkale - Gelibolu"]=350;
 Kp_bedel["Edirne - Tekirdağ"]=350;
 
 var Mp_bedel= new Array();
 Mp_bedel["Atatürk Airport (IST)"]=40;
 Mp_bedel["Sabiha Gökçen Airport (SAW)"]=60;
 Mp_bedel["Ports - Karaköy, Salıpazarı, Kabataş"]=40;
 Mp_bedel["Old City - Sultanahmet - Sirkeci"]=35;
 Mp_bedel["Taksim - Beyoğlu, Pera, Nişantaşı"]=35;
 Mp_bedel["Beşiktaş - Ortaköy"]=0;
 Mp_bedel["Yenikapı - Aksaray, Laleli"]=15;
 Mp_bedel["Bakırköy - Yenibosna, Zeytinburnu, Sefaköy"]=0;
 Mp_bedel["Otogar - Bayrampaşa, Bağcılar, Esenler"]=30;
 Mp_bedel["Şişli - Maslak, Levent, Etiler"]=0;
 Mp_bedel["Topkapı - Fındıkzade, Vatan Cad"]=30;
 Mp_bedel["Eyüp - Gaziosmanpaşa, Haliç"]=40;
 Mp_bedel["Mecidiyeköy - Bomonti, Çağlayan"]=0;
 Mp_bedel["Avcılar - Beylikdüzü, Esenyurt"]=50;
 Mp_bedel["Pendik - Tuzla, Kurtköy"]=60;
 Mp_bedel["Kadıköy - Ataşehir, Bostancı"]=55;
 Mp_bedel["Silivri - Selimpaşa, Kumburgaz"]=85;
 Mp_bedel["Üsküdar - Harem, Haydarpaşa"]=55;
 Mp_bedel["Kartal - Maltepe, Ümraniye"]=55;
 Mp_bedel["Kilyos"]=85;
 Mp_bedel["Şile - Ağva"]=90;
 Mp_bedel["Beykoz - Kavacık, And.Hisarı"]=60;
 Mp_bedel["Sarıyer- Tarabya, Yeniköy"]=45;
 Mp_bedel["Gebze"]=80;
 Mp_bedel["Izmit"]=115;
 Mp_bedel["Bursa - Uludağ"]=320;
 Mp_bedel["Bolu - Abant"]=320;
 Mp_bedel["Yalova"]=220;
 Mp_bedel["Çanakkale - Gelibolu"]=350;
 Mp_bedel["Edirne - Tekirdağ"]=350;
 
 var Pp_bedel= new Array();
 Pp_bedel["Atatürk Airport (IST)"]=55;
 Pp_bedel["Sabiha Gökçen Airport (SAW)"]=55;
 Pp_bedel["Ports - Karaköy, Salıpazarı, Kabataş"]=50;
 Pp_bedel["Old City - Sultanahmet - Sirkeci"]=50;
 Pp_bedel["Taksim - Beyoğlu, Pera, Nişantaşı"]=50;
 Pp_bedel["Beşiktaş - Ortaköy"]=50;
 Pp_bedel["Yenikapı - Aksaray, Laleli"]=55;
 Pp_bedel["Bakırköy - Yenibosna, Zeytinburnu, Sefaköy"]=65;
 Pp_bedel["Otogar - Bayrampaşa, Bağcılar, Esenler"]=60;
 Pp_bedel["Şişli - Maslak, Levent, Etiler"]=40;
 Pp_bedel["Topkapı - Fındıkzade, Vatan Cad"]=55;
 Pp_bedel["Eyüp - Gaziosmanpaşa, Haliç"]=0;
 Pp_bedel["Mecidiyeköy - Bomonti, Çağlayan"]=55;
 Pp_bedel["Avcılar - Beylikdüzü, Esenyurt"]=80;
 Pp_bedel["Pendik - Tuzla, Kurtköy"]=55;
 Pp_bedel["Kadıköy - Ataşehir, Bostancı"]=0;
 Pp_bedel["Silivri - Selimpaşa, Kumburgaz"]=120;
 Pp_bedel["Üsküdar - Harem, Haydarpaşa"]=50;
 Pp_bedel["Kartal - Maltepe, Ümraniye"]=50;
 Pp_bedel["Kilyos"]=95;
 Pp_bedel["Şile - Ağva"]=85;
 Pp_bedel["Beykoz - Kavacık, And.Hisarı"]=0;
 Pp_bedel["Sarıyer- Tarabya, Yeniköy"]=65;
 Pp_bedel["Gebze"]=75;
 Pp_bedel["Izmit"]=110;
 Pp_bedel["Bursa - Uludağ"]=320;
 Pp_bedel["Bolu - Abant"]=320;
 Pp_bedel["Yalova"]=220;
 Pp_bedel["Çanakkale - Gelibolu"]=350;
 Pp_bedel["Edirne - Tekirdağ"]=350;
 
 var Rp_bedel= new Array();
 Rp_bedel["Atatürk Airport (IST)"]=50;
 Rp_bedel["Sabiha Gökçen Airport (SAW)"]=50;
 Rp_bedel["Ports - Karaköy, Salıpazarı, Kabataş"]=50;
 Rp_bedel["Old City - Sultanahmet - Sirkeci"]=50;
 Rp_bedel["Taksim - Beyoğlu, Pera, Nişantaşı"]=50;
 Rp_bedel["Beşiktaş - Ortaköy"]=50;
 Rp_bedel["Yenikapı - Aksaray, Laleli"]=50;
 Rp_bedel["Bakırköy - Yenibosna, Zeytinburnu, Sefaköy"]=65;
 Rp_bedel["Otogar - Bayrampaşa, Bağcılar, Esenler"]=60;
 Rp_bedel["Şişli - Maslak, Levent, Etiler"]=45;
 Rp_bedel["Topkapı - Fındıkzade, Vatan Cad"]=55;
 Rp_bedel["Eyüp - Gaziosmanpaşa, Haliç"]=75;
 Rp_bedel["Mecidiyeköy - Bomonti, Çağlayan"]=60;
 Rp_bedel["Avcılar - Beylikdüzü, Esenyurt"]=80;
 Rp_bedel["Pendik - Tuzla, Kurtköy"]=55;
 Rp_bedel["Kadıköy - Ataşehir, Bostancı"]=50;
 Rp_bedel["Silivri - Selimpaşa, Kumburgaz"]=120;
 Rp_bedel["Üsküdar - Harem, Haydarpaşa"]=55;
 Rp_bedel["Kartal - Maltepe, Ümraniye"]=50;
 Rp_bedel["Kilyos"]=95;
 Rp_bedel["Şile - Ağva"]=85;
 Rp_bedel["Beykoz - Kavacık, And.Hisarı"]=0;
 Rp_bedel["Sarıyer- Tarabya, Yeniköy"]=65;
 Rp_bedel["Gebze"]=75;
 Rp_bedel["Izmit"]=110;
 Rp_bedel["Bursa - Uludağ"]=320;
 Rp_bedel["Bolu - Abant"]=320;
 Rp_bedel["Yalova"]=220;
 Rp_bedel["Çanakkale - Gelibolu"]=350;
 Rp_bedel["Edirne - Tekirdağ"]=350;
 
 var kisi_bedel= new Array();
 kisi_bedel["Standart 4 Pax"]=0;
 kisi_bedel["Minibus 8 pax"]=15;
 kisi_bedel["Midibus 13 pax"]=25;
  
function getCakeSizePrice()
{  
    var cakeSizePrice=0;
    var theForm = document.forms["slider-form"];
    var snereden = theForm.elements["nereden_y"];
    var snereye = theForm.elements["nereye_y"];
    var sorgu = document.getElementById("nereden_y");
    
    if(sorgu[sorgu.selectedIndex].value=="Atatürk Airport (IST)")
        {
            cakeSizePrice = nereden_bedel[snereden.value] + Ap_bedel[snereye.value];
        }
    if(sorgu[sorgu.selectedIndex].value=="Sabiha Gökçen Airport (SAW)")
        {
            cakeSizePrice = nereden_bedel[snereden.value] + Bp_bedel[snereye.value];
        }
    if(sorgu[sorgu.selectedIndex].value=="Ports - Karaköy, Salıpazarı, Kabataş")
        {
            cakeSizePrice = nereden_bedel[snereden.value] + Cp_bedel[snereye.value];
        }
    if(sorgu[sorgu.selectedIndex].value=="Old City - Sultanahmet - Sirkeci")
        {
            cakeSizePrice = nereden_bedel[snereden.value] + Dp_bedel[snereye.value];
        }
    if(sorgu[sorgu.selectedIndex].value=="Taksim - Beyoğlu, Pera, Nişantaşı")
        {
            cakeSizePrice = nereden_bedel[snereden.value] + Ep_bedel[snereye.value];
        }
    if(sorgu[sorgu.selectedIndex].value=="Beşiktaş - Ortaköy")
        {
            cakeSizePrice = nereden_bedel[snereden.value] + Fp_bedel[snereye.value];
        }
    if(sorgu[sorgu.selectedIndex].value=="Yenikapı - Aksaray, Laleli")
        {
            cakeSizePrice = nereden_bedel[snereden.value] + Gp_bedel[snereye.value];
        }
    if(sorgu[sorgu.selectedIndex].value=="Bakırköy - Yenibosna, Zeytinburnu, Sefaköy")
        {
            cakeSizePrice = nereden_bedel[snereden.value] + Hp_bedel[snereye.value];
        }
    if(sorgu[sorgu.selectedIndex].value=="Otogar - Bayrampaşa, Bağcılar, Esenler")
        {
            cakeSizePrice = nereden_bedel[snereden.value] + Ip_bedel[snereye.value];
        }
    if(sorgu[sorgu.selectedIndex].value=="Şişli - Maslak, Levent, Etiler")
        {
            cakeSizePrice = nereden_bedel[snereden.value] + Jp_bedel[snereye.value];
        }
    if(sorgu[sorgu.selectedIndex].value=="Topkapı - Fındıkzade, Vatan Cad")
        {
            cakeSizePrice = nereden_bedel[snereden.value] + Kp_bedel[snereye.value];
        }
    if(sorgu[sorgu.selectedIndex].value=="Eyüp - Gaziosmanpaşa, Haliç")
        {
            cakeSizePrice = nereden_bedel[snereden.value] + Lp_bedel[snereye.value];
        }
    if(sorgu[sorgu.selectedIndex].value=="Mecidiyeköy - Bomonti, Çağlayan")
        {
            cakeSizePrice = nereden_bedel[snereden.value] + Mp_bedel[snereye.value];
        }
    if(sorgu[sorgu.selectedIndex].value=="Kadıköy - Ataşehir, Bostancı")
        {
            cakeSizePrice = nereden_bedel[snereden.value] + Pp_bedel[snereye.value];
        }
    if(sorgu[sorgu.selectedIndex].value=="Üsküdar - Harem, Haydarpaşa")
        {
            cakeSizePrice = nereden_bedel[snereden.value] + Rp_bedel[snereye.value];
        }
    return cakeSizePrice;
}

function getkisi_yPrice()
{
    var cakekisi_yPrice=0;
    var theForm = document.forms["slider-form"];
    var selectedkisi_y = theForm.elements["kisi_y"];

    cakekisi_yPrice = kisi_bedel[selectedkisi_y.value];

    return cakekisi_yPrice;
}
        
function calculateTotal()
{
    var cakePrice = getCakeSizePrice() + getkisi_yPrice();
    if(isNaN(cakePrice)) {
               cakePrice = '0';
                }  
    
    var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
    divobj.style.display='block';
    
    divobj.innerHTML = Math.abs(cakePrice)+"€";

}

function hideTotal()
{
    var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
    divobj.style.display='block';
}
```

```html
<form id="slider-form" class="main-form" action="http://istanbulprivateservice.com/bookit.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="POST">
  <div class="main_form_navigation">
   <div id="book_car" class="title-form current">BOOKING ONLINE</div>
  </div>
  <div id="book_car_content" class="content-form ">
   
<div class="form-block car-type">
<div class="car-type-select">
<h4>Pick Up Location</h4>
<select class="select" id="nereden_y" name="nereden_y" onchange="calculateTotal()" >
<option value="">Select</option>
<option value="Atatürk Airport (IST)" selected="selected">Atatürk Airport (IST)</option>
<option value="Sabiha Gökçen Airport (SAW)">Sabiha Gökçen Airport (SAW)</option>
<option value="Ports - Karaköy, Salıpazarı, Kabataş">Ports - Karaköy, Salıpazarı, Kabataş</option>
<option value="Old City - Sultanahmet - Sirkeci">Old City - Sultanahmet - Sirkeci</option>
<option value="Taksim - Beyoğlu, Pera, Nişantaşı">Taksim - Beyoğlu, Pera, Nişantaşı</option>
<option value="Beşiktaş - Ortaköy">Beşiktaş - Ortaköy</option>
<option value="Yenikapı - Aksaray, Laleli">Yenikapı - Aksaray, Laleli</option>
<option value="Bakırköy - Yenibosna, Zeytinburnu, Sefaköy">Bakırköy - Yenibosna, Zeytinburnu, Sefaköy</option>
<option value="Otogar - Bayrampaşa, Bağcılar, Esenler">Otogar - Bayrampaşa, Bağcılar, Esenler</option>
<option value="Şişli - Maslak, Levent, Etiler">Şişli - Maslak, Levent, Etiler</option>
<option value="Topkapı - Fındıkzade, Vatan Cad">Topkapı - Fındıkzade, Vatan Cad</option>
<option value="Eyüp - Gaziosmanpaşa, Haliç">Eyüp - Gaziosmanpaşa, Haliç</option>
<option value="Mecidiyeköy - Bomonti, Çağlayan">Mecidiyeköy - Bomonti, Çağlayan</option>
<option value="Kadıköy - Ataşehir, Bostancı">Kadıköy - Ataşehir, Bostancı</option>
<option value="Üsküdar - Harem, Haydarpaşa">Üsküdar - Harem, Haydarpaşa</option>
</select>
</div>
   
<div class="form-block car-type">
<div class="car-type-select">
<h4>Drop Off Location</h4>
<select class="select" id="nereye_y" name="nereye_y" onchange="calculateTotal()" sb="88701315" >
<option value="" selected="selected">Select</option>
<option value="Atatürk Airport (IST)" selected="selected">Atatürk Airport (IST)</option>
<option value="Sabiha Gökçen Airport (SAW)" selected="selected">Sabiha Gökçen Airport (SAW)</option>
<option value="Ports - Karaköy, Salıpazarı, Kabataş">Ports - Karaköy, Salıpazarı, Kabataş</option>
<option value="Old City - Sultanahmet - Sirkeci">Old City - Sultanahmet - Sirkeci</option>
<option value="Taksim - Beyoğlu, Pera, Nişantaşı">Taksim - Beyoğlu, Pera, Nişantaşı</option>
<option value="Beşiktaş - Ortaköy">Beşiktaş - Ortaköy</option>
<option value="Yenikapı - Aksaray, Laleli">Yenikapı - Aksaray, Laleli</option>
<option value="Bakırköy - Yenibosna, Zeytinburnu, Sefaköy" selected="selected">Bakırköy - Yenibosna, Zeytinburnu, Sefaköy</option>
<option value="Otogar - Bayrampaşa, Bağcılar, Esenler">Otogar - Bayrampaşa, Bağcılar, Esenler</option>
<option value="Şişli - Maslak, Levent, Etiler">Şişli - Maslak, Levent, Etiler</option>
<option value="Topkapı - Fındıkzade, Vatan Cad" selected="selected">Topkapı - Fındıkzade, Vatan Cad</option>
<option value="Eyüp - Gaziosmanpaşa, Haliç">Eyüp - Gaziosmanpaşa, Haliç</option>
<option value="Mecidiyeköy - Bomonti, Çağlayan">Mecidiyeköy - Bomonti, Çağlayan</option>
<option value="Avcılar - Beylikdüzü, Esenyurt">Avcılar - Beylikdüzü, Esenyurt</option>
<option value="Pendik - Tuzla, Kurtköy">Pendik - Tuzla, Kurtköy</option>
<option value="Kadıköy - Ataşehir, Bostancı">Kadıköy - Ataşehir, Bostancı</option>
<option value="Silivri - Selimpaşa, Kumburgaz">Silivri - Selimpaşa, Kumburgaz</option>
<option value="Üsküdar - Harem, Haydarpaşa" selected="selected">Üsküdar - Harem, Haydarpaşa</option>
<option value="Kartal - Maltepe, Ümraniye">Kartal - Maltepe, Ümraniye</option>
<option value="Kilyos">Kilyos</option>
<option value="Şile - Ağva">Şile - Ağva</option>
<option value="Beykoz - Kavacık, And.Hisarı">Beykoz - Kavacık, And.Hisarı</option>
<option value="Sarıyer- Tarabya, Yeniköy">Sarıyer- Tarabya, Yeniköy</option>
<option value="Gebze">Gebze</option>
<option value="Izmit">Izmit</option>
<option value="Bursa - Uludağ">Bursa - Uludağ</option>
<option value="Bolu - Abant">Bolu - Abant</option>
<option value="Yalova">Yalova</option>
<option value="Çanakkale - Gelibolu">Çanakkale - Gelibolu</option>
<option value="Edirne - Tekirdağ">Edirne - Tekirdağ</option>
</select>
</div>
 
<h4>Passenger</h4>
<div class="car-type-select">
 <select class="select" id="kisi_y" name="kisi_y" onchange="calculateTotal()"> 
  <option selected="selected" value="Standart 4 Pax">Standart 4 Pax</option>
  <option value="Minibus 8 pax" selected="selected">Minibus 8 pax</option>
  <option value="Midibus 13 pax" selected="selected">Midibus 13 pax</option>
 </select>
   
   <h4>Price</h4>
<textarea class="price-text" id="totalPrice" name="totalPrice" readonly="" style="display: block;">65€</textarea>
```

Comment: Oh, now i got it, i wouldn't find if you didn't say:) Thank you very much.